# ES6 React JS methods Calendar Component

Tags: javascript, methods, reactjs, ecmascript-6, rendering

I am creating a calendar component and at the moment can't work out why react won't render to the DOM the returned elements of my `renderWeekDays` method?

Currently I have the following:

```
export default class CalendarApp extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();

    // Bind Methods
    this.renderWeekDays = this.renderWeekDays.bind(this);
}

renderWeekDays() {
    return (
        <tr><td>Render Week days Please</td></tr>
    )
}

render() {
    let overviewContent,
        checkRates

    // Add Check rates and availability section if Rooms page
    if (this.props.roomPage) {
        checkRates = (
            <div>
                <h2>Check rates and availability</h2>
                <small>or call us on <a href="tel:03301003180">0330 100 3180</a></small>
            </div>
        )
    }

    // Determine whether to show placeholder or actual dates
    if (this.props.dateSelected) {
        overviewContent = (
            <div>
                <span className="icon">Icon</span>
                <span className="date-from">21 Jun</span>
                <span className="seperate">-></span>
                <span className="date-to">25 Jun</span>
                <span className="clear">X</span>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        overviewContent = ( 
            <div>
                <span className="icon">Icon</span>
                <span className="check-in">Check-in</span>
                <span className="seperate">-></span>
                <span className="check-out">Check-out</span>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className="calendar hotelroom-follow-calendar">
            { checkRates }
            <div className="calendar-overview">
                <button>
                    { overviewContent }
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="calendar-container">
                <div className="calendar-month">
                    <span className="previous">Prev</span>
                    June
                    <span className="next">Next</span> 
                </div>
                <table className="calendar-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>M</td>
                            <td>T</td>
                            <td>W</td>
                            <td>T</td>
                            <td>F</td>
                            <td>S</td>
                            <td>S</td>
                        </tr> 
                    </thead> 
                    <tbody>
                        { this.renderWeekDays }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            { Moment().format() }
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am not being presented with any errors, it simply won't load in `<tr><td>Render Week days Please</td></tr>`.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have double checked all bind() methods etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually invoke the function in your jsx.

```
<tbody>
    { this.renderWeekDays }
</tbody>
```

needs to be

```
<tbody>
    { this.renderWeekDays() }
</tbody>
```

and voila, it should work!

Comment: Schoolboy error! Thanks for noticing this. It actually turns out I don't need to .bind(this) either.